# SQLite query using SQLite CONCAT operator ( || ) return uppercase text (when doesn't) USING DATA ADAPTER

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

In .Net 4.0 on Windows 8.1 using System.Data.SQLite 1.0.80 I execute a query against a DB.
The table is very simple has only one column named `CODE (VARCHAR)`.

The query is:

```
SELECT (CODE||'.jpg') as IMG_NAME FROM TESTTABLE
```

if execute the query in a external SQLite manager like NAVICAT the result is for example:

```
1824.jpg
1825.jpg
```

if i execute from code using DataAdapeter like this

```
SQLiteDataAdapter adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd);
        adapter.FillLoadOption = LoadOption.OverwriteChanges;
        adapter.AcceptChangesDuringFill = false;
        DataSet dataset = new DataSet(NomeTabella);
        adapter.Fill(dataset);
        adapter.Dispose();
        return dataset.Tables[0];
```

when reading the table field containing the result in this way:

```
  foreach (DataRow row in datatable.Rows)
        {
            var code = row["IMG_NAME"]
        }
```

the result is with the 'JPG' text UPPERCASE and not LOWERCASE like in the original select. Example:

```
1824.JPG
1825.JPG
```

How is this possible?